# How to return emails with imap_search SINCE using hours

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I have a php script returning gmail emails. What I'm trying to do is to catch just the emails received in the last hour. Is it possible?

```
$date = date("D, j M Y H:i:s +0000", strtotime("-1 hour")); 
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "'.$date.'"');
```

$date is displaying:
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 20:42:20 +0000

But emails date looks like this:
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 14:22:12 -0800 (PST) <-- this is an email received 2h ago.

The script is returning all emails for the day.

Comment: `SINCE` only operates on dates. If you want to perform additional filtering based on the time you'll have to do that in the application. ref: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4

Comment: And dates have to be in dd-MON-YYYY format.  Like, 12-Jan-2017